# Окажется недовольным/ Окажется недоволен

Tags: общие-вопросы

Сколько раз сталкиваюсь, всегда ставит в тупик. Мне кажется, что формулировка "Окажется недоволен" существует, по крайней мере, она на слуху. Или "ворд" правильно требует исправления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильность употребления зависит от контекста:  он **окажется недовольным** (общая оценка) и он **окажется недоволен чем-то**.

Довольный/недовольный человек - это (1) **безусловное (абсолютное) состояние**, но чаще речь идет о довольстве или недовольстве (2)**какими-либо обстоятельствами** (эти обстоятельства выражаются **зависимыми словами**) и тогда следует употреблять **не полную, а краткую форму**.

Это следует из "**Практической стилистики Розенталя**", который указывал на способность краткой формы к управлению, в отличие от полной формы. Например: он болен ангиной, нельзя сказать: он больной ангиной.

Примеры:

1) Даже, если ваш продукт сработает идеально, как вы задумывали, клиент все равно может **оказаться недовольным**.

2) Губернатор  оказался **недоволен** (чем?) **работой** глав тех районов, где горят леса.

**Из словаря**

ДОВОЛЬНЫЙ,  Испытывающий чувство удовольствия, удовлетворения; выражающий чувство удовольствия. Д. человек. Довольное лицо. Он **доволен жизнью**. Учитель **доволен своим учеником**.

Comment: В примере с ангиной управление в обоих вариантах одинаково эффективное ("болен ангиной" и "больной ангиной" - сочетания равноценные), разная _управляемость_ "слева": он болен ангиной; это больной ангиной.

Answer (score -1):

Краткие формы прилагательных и причастий сейчас массово заменяются полными во всех случаях, кроме основного использования (с глаголом "быть"). Глагол "оказаться" имеет очень слабую модальную и вспомогательную роль, поэтому я бы согласился с формой "недовольным". К тому же форма "окажется какой/каков" (Им. п.)тоже испытывает давление со стороны "окажется каким/каковым" (Тв. п.). Это еще один довод в пользу "недовольным".

> Или "ворд" правильно требует исправления?

Ворд может требовать что угодно, ориентируйтесь на более авторитетные источники.